# Convert escaped HTML string to Javascript object (No JQuery)

Tags: javascript

I'm practicing my Javascript by making a browser plugin to display external comment from Reddit on other webpages. The comments come in this format:

```
    &lt;div class="md"&gt;&lt;p&gt;I have them all over my yard. I didn&amp;#39;t realize they spread so bad when I planted them.
They look cool with early morning dew on them though.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
```

I need to re-introduce the HTML characters (i.e. `&lt;div&gt;` => `<div>`), in order to put the formatted HTML onto the page.

Is there some native functionality Javascript provides to do this?

From what I can tell: `x = document.createElement("div"); x.innerHTML = rawComment` does not work, as the HTML is escaped, and the innerHTML returns a `<div>` with a string in it instead of a series of DOM nodes.

Comment: What have you done to research this? you are expected to have at least done basic research before asking questions here and I really find it hard to believe that you couldn't at leaast have found a start point

Comment: My research lead me to document.createElement, but it didn't work with encoded HTML values. It's odd that you're so hostile about a question. In fact, I don't see why your comment was at all necessary at all.

Comment: Not hostile but if you read the help center will see that it is incumbent on you to show some sort of effort to resolve issues yourself. This isn't a code writing service or a *"how to*" tutorial service either. There are numerous approaches to resolving this and numerous similar posts on this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you might try to do is the following:

```
// some dummy deocded text
let encoded = '&lt;div class="md"&gt;&lt;p&gt;I have them all over my yard.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;';

// create a new textarea and insert your encoded text
let dummyElement = document.createElement('textarea');
dummyElement.innerHTML = encoded;

// retrieve the textarea's value, which will be your decoded text
let decoded = dummyElement.value;
// decoded will be: <div class="md"><p>I have them all over my yard.</p></div>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/195fbsnm/)

This will work *without jQuery*, as you're only using the pure Javascript function's of your browser.

Comment: Very clever, Robin! I assume this is working only because we're using a textarea, right? It's a great solution. Thanks!